# How to prevent UITextField from going below an UIImageView after using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextfield, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to add an image to a UIImageView, but when I do it goes on top of the UITextField. How do I make sure the UITextField stays in front of the UIImageView?

Below is my code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.myImageView.image = image
        self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode(rawValue: 1)!
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I tried to add the UITextField to the view again like this, but it didn't work:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.myImageView.image = image
        self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode(rawValue: 1)!
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(textFieldTop)
        self.view.addSubview(textFieldBottom)
    }
}
```

**Update**
So I realized the problem did not lie with what was in front but for some reason my foreground color is automatically turning transparent and cannot be set with the foreground attribute below.

```
let textAttributes = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : 3.0
]
```

Comment: have you tried setting `clipsToBounds` on your `UIImageView`?

Comment: No I haven't tried that.

Comment: No. I needed to set my NSStrokeWidthAttribute to - 3

Comment: got it, didn't see your update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set NSStrokeWidthAttribute to -3.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(viewYouWantToBeOnTop)
```